# Lodash Merge 2 Different event Type by date as one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am looking to manipulate the data so two different events which are named differently(but are part of same location) can be merged into 1 object in the collection using lodash

```
var events = [
  {
    count: 2,
    date: "2020-01-20",
    type: "Event_1"
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-16",
    type: "Event_1"
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-16",
    type: "EVENT_2"
  },
  {
    count: 2,
    date: "2020-01-16",
    type: "EVENT_3"
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-22",
    type: "EVENT_2"
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-22",
    type: "EVENT_3"
  }
];
```

Merge type **EVENT_2** and **EVENT_3** from the **same date** and increase the counter by doing an addition of count key for both types

For eg

```
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-22",
    type: "EVENT_2"
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-22",
    type: "EVENT_3"
  }
```

will become i.e. EVENT

```
  {
    count: 2,
    date: "2020-01-22",
    type: "EVENT_2"
  }
```

Final result will look like

```
[
  {
    count: 2,
    date: "2020-01-20",
    type: "Event_1"
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    date: "2020-01-16",
    type: "Event_1"
  },
  {
    count: 3,
    date: "2020-01-16",
    type: "EVENT_2"
  },
  {
    count: 2,
    date: "2020-01-22",
    type: "EVENT_2"
  },
];
```

My initial [attempt is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-tester-qrpzt?file=/index.js)

Comment: So you want to group these objects by `date`, increasing the counts accordingly, and each grouping object has the `type` field set to the first encoutered value in the group sub-list?

Comment: Please show what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: Yes right based on the date yet combining two different events

Comment: Shouldn't the second and third objects in your final result array be grouped together? They do have the same date.

Comment: My attempt is within my question (last line) here is link again https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-tester-0y93f

Comment: Only EVENT_2 and EVENT_3 are supposed to be grouped together , Sorry if its confusing event_1 remains as is , so I am trying to club events by location (event location) event_2 and event_3 are happening on same location hence they need to be clubbed. Hope this helps

Comment: It sounds like the grouping is not done by date, it should be done by location like you said, so unless each event object has a field called `location` that we can use to do the grouping, or maybe another configuration object that maps event types to locations, I'm afraid this cannot be done.

Comment: we do not have location and only event_2 and event_3 will be at same place . I will keep trying